# Converting VMs from XenServer to OpenStack (KVM)

Tags: kvm-virtualization, xenserver, openstack

I'm looking at moving our XenServer cluster (150 VMs) to OpenStack on KVM.  After extensive reading it looks like virt-v2v will do this.  However I'm confused about it's usage.

I was going to copy the VHD file and then run virt-v2v on this, then import into Glance, and start an instance. However it appears this isn't the process virt-v2v uses.

Could someone explain the overall process, how to use virt-v2v or any other tool(s) that I will need to convert VMs from XenServer to KVM and import into OpenStack.

The two 'clouds' are separate hardware, over the internet - so i would like to avoid shared storage between them if that's possible, however if it makes it too complex we can sling up a VPN between.

Comment: what is the format of you VM's at the moment?

Comment: They're CentOS 6/7 VMs, most PVM, some HVM.  Running live on XenServer at the moment, so the disk is a .vhd.

Comment: qemu-img will convert them quite easily http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/convert-images.html

Comment: This has worked, but what about adding in the libvirt bits and pieces for console etc?